# Timeline with vertical line and dots over it not aligned

Tags: html, css

So, i am working on a portfolio and I was trying to do a timeline type thing with a vertical line down the middle and some dots that go over the vertical line. I have both the vertical line and the dots working, however I can not seem to place them on top of one another. The dots seem to be off to the side, like right by 2rem.

```css
 #vertical-line{
    border-left: 2.5px solid white;
    height: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;

  }


.dot {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: var(--blue);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .main-body{
  padding-left:15rem;
  padding-right:15rem;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }

  #product-flow{
  background-color: var(--yellow);
  padding-bottom:3rem;
  }

  #product-flow > div:nth-of-type(1){
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .main-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-row-gap:5rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  } 
  
  .three-column-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 3rem;
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: center;
  }

 .container{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto;
 grid-row-gap:10rem;
 justify-content: center;
 }

 .container2{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto;
 grid-row-gap:5rem;
 }
   
  #container-box-1{
    grid-area: box1;
  }
  #container-box-2{
    grid-area: box2;
  }
  #container-box-3{
    grid-area: box3;
  }
  #container-box-4{
    grid-area: box4;
  }
  #container-box-5{
    grid-area: box5;
  }
```

```html
<!-- PRODUCT FLOW STARTS -->
      <section class="main-body" id="product-flow">
        <div class="main-grid">
          <div>
            <h4>PRODUCT FLOW</h4>
            <h3>what would a happy path for a persona look like<br>
            Andrew is leaving work and wants to plan an after work
            activity for his team and him
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- GRID WITHIN GRIDS -->
        <div class="three-column-grid">
          <div>
            <div class="container">
              <div id="container-box-1">
                <h6>Locate area on map</h6>
                <p>The app allows users to zoom into an area in a city where their searches will be located</p>
              </div>
              <div id="container-box-2">
                <h6>Filter for the category</h6>
                <p>User is able to select the categories he is interested in, in this case user would select nightlife and food</p>
              </div id="container-box-3">
              <div>
                <h6>Share Event to Story</h6>
                <p>The app allows user to interact with an event by sharing through text or sharing to your story so others can see what you're up to. This makes it easier for Andrews friends to see where they are going</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div id="vertical-line" class="container2">
              <span class="dot"></span>
              <span class="dot"></span>
              <span class="dot"></span>
              <span class="dot"></span>
              <span class="dot"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="container">
              <div id="container-box-4">
                <h6>Set date for availability</h6>
                <p>Under the filter section, select which time frame you are looking for, in this case user would select "TONIGHT"</p>
              </div>
              <div id="container-box-5">
                <h6>Select event</h6>
                <p>Selecting the specific event allows for information to pop up about the event where there are several interaction options</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

```
<!-- PRODUCT FLOW ENDS -->
```

CSS:

```
 #vertical-line{
    border-left: 2.5px solid white;
    height: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;

  }


.dot {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: var(--blue);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you have enough of your code included here.  There are a bunch of classes that you've not included the CSS for ....

Comment: @Craig sorry about that, i didnt think the other css was what is altering or causing the issue, but I have updated it now